# I changed web.php in laravel 5.6 routes but still give me old routes

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

I changed **routes/web.php** in **Laravel** but still, it gives me the old routes from days ago, I cleared the cache using `route:clear` and cached again.
I also tried on another browser and cleared cookies but laravel gives me the old routes..
In past I used `Route::redirect('/here','/there',301);`
but now I changed the file to `Route::redirect('/here','/notThere',301);` 
but still it gives me **/there** when I go to **/here**.

Comment: plz provide the routes code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing your browser cache, the browser can cache 301 redirects, and it won't pick up further changes in your app.

Comment: thank you, it solved the problem but every time I change the route file I should clear the cache of the browser?

Comment: Only when using 301 redirects. A 301 redirect means "Moved Permanently", so the browser assumes that redirect will never change.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing `php artisan route:clear`, are there routes after or before the redirct?

Comment: thank you, it helped, I tried to clear the routes but it didn't change, yes the routes are after the redirect. I found out it was because of the cache of the browser.

Comment: Nice ! Have fun with coding.